# Sql LeftJoin taking long time

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 table say abc and xyz.
I am performing Left join over it.Query is as follows:-

```
Select Distinct ON (S1.xyz_id) S1.data as data,S1.time as xyztme
,S2.receiver,S2.time,S2.msgdata,S1.abc_id as abc_id
,S2.account,S2.identifier,S2.unit
from abc S2
 left join xyz S1
  on   S2.receiver=S1.sender
  and S1.type=S2.type
 where  S2.userid=:systemuserId
 and S1.time Between :startdate and :enddate
 and S2.time Between :startdate and :enddate
 Order By S1.xyz_id, S2.time desc;
```

This takes a long time to execute that is executes forever but when I remove S2.time Between :startdate and :enddate from query,Time is less but still takes for suppose around 2 minutes to bring 20 records.Following is the query:-

```
Select Distinct ON (S1.xyz_id) S1.data as data,S1.time as xyztme
,S2.receiver,S2.time,S2.msgdata,S1.abc_id as abc_id
,S2.account,S2.identifier,S2.unit
 from abc S2
 left join xyz S1
 on   S2.receiver=S1.sender
  and S1.type=S2.type
 where  S2.userid=:systemuserId
 and S1.time Between :startdate and :enddate
 Order By S1.xyz_id, S2.time desc;
```

I am using Postgresql 10.What could be the cause for taking so much time to provide the response even when there are less records.How can I improve the response time.It's regarding fetching responses to messages sent.If I need to specify more details,please let me know.Any Help would be appreciable.Thanks.

Query Plan for both queries:-

```
pl4sms=> EXPLAIN ANALYZE Select S1.data as data,S1.time as xyztme ,S2.receiver,S2.time,S2.msgdata,S1.abc_id as abc_id ,S2.account,S2.identifier,S2.unit from abc S2 left join xyz S1 on   S2.receiver=S1.sender  and S1.type=S2.type  where  S2.userid='119007423' and S1.time Between '2019-09-16 00:00:00' and '2019-09-18 00:00:00'  and S2.time Between '2019-09-16 00:00:00' and '2019-09-18 00:00:00' Order By S1.xyz_id, S2.time desc;

                                                                                              QUERY PLAN

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------

     Sort  (cost=63814.63..63814.64 rows=1 width=299) (actual time=262530.127..262530.129 rows=11 loops=1)
       Sort Key: s1.xyz_id, s2."time" DESC
       Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 36kB
       ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1000.43..63814.62 rows=1 width=299) (actual time=430.382..262529.979 rows=11 loops=1)
             Join Filter: (((s2.receiver)::text = (s1.sender)::text) AND ((s2.type)::text = (s1.type)::text))
             Rows Removed by Join Filter: 107719
             ->  Index Scan using abc_time_userid_idx on xyz s2  (cost=0.43..8518.11 rows=1 width=241) (actual time=32.687..682.722 rows=1890 loops=
    1)
                   Index Cond: (("time" >= '2019-09-16 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ("time" <= '2019-09-18 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ((user
    id)::text = '119007423'::text))
             ->  Gather  (cost=1000.00..55296.49 rows=1 width=82) (actual time=67.608..138.486 rows=57 loops=1890)
                   Workers Planned: 2
                   Workers Launched: 2
                   ->  Parallel Seq Scan on xyz s1  (cost=0.00..54296.39 rows=1 width=82) (actual time=63.781..126.347 rows=19 loops=5670)
                         Filter: (("time" >= '2019-09-16 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ("time" <= '2019-09-18 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
                         Rows Removed by Filter: 1278
     Planning time: 1.829 ms
     Execution time: 262532.245 ms
    (16 rows)
```

```
pl4sms=> EXPLAIN ANALYZE Select S1.data as data,S1.time as xyztme
,S2.receiver,S2.time,S2.msgdata,S1.abc_id as abc_id
,S2.account,S2.identifier,S2.unit from abc S2 left join xyz S1 on   S2.receiver=S1.sender  and S1.type=S2.type  where  S2.userid='119007423' and S1.time Between '2019-09-16 00:00:00' and '2019-09-18 00:00:00' and S2.time Between '2019-09-16 00:00:00' and '2019-09-18 00:00:00' Order By S1.xyz_id, S2.time desc;

--------------------------------------------------------------

        Sort  (cost=63814.63..63814.64 rows=1 width=299) (actual time=262530.127..262530.129 rows=11 loops=1)
       Sort Key: s1.xyz_id, s2."time" DESC
       Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 36kB
       ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1000.43..63814.62 rows=1 width=299) (actual time=430.382..262529.979 rows=11 loops=1)
             Join Filter: (((s2.receiver)::text = (s1.sender)::text) AND ((s2.type)::text = (s1.type)::text))
             Rows Removed by Join Filter: 107719
             ->  Index Scan using abc_time_userid_idx on xyz s2  (cost=0.43..8518.11 rows=1 width=241) (actual time=32.687..682.722 rows=1890 loops=
    1)
                   Index Cond: (("time" >= '2019-09-16 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ("time" <= '2019-09-18 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ((user
    id)::text = '119007423'::text))
             ->  Gather  (cost=1000.00..55296.49 rows=1 width=82) (actual time=67.608..138.486 rows=57 loops=1890)
                   Workers Planned: 2
                   Workers Launched: 2
                   ->  Parallel Seq Scan on xyz s1  (cost=0.00..54296.39 rows=1 width=82) (actual time=63.781..126.347 rows=19 loops=5670)
                         Filter: (("time" >= '2019-09-16 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ("time" <= '2019-09-18 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
                         Rows Removed by Filter: 1278
     Planning time: 1.829 ms
     Execution time: 262532.245 ms
    (16 rows)
```

Comment: There are numerous possible reasons. Bad or missing indexes, huge data sets or even a broken hard drive. Please add the output from the query planner (EXPLAIN ANALYZE <your query>). My first guess is `DISTINCT ON` slows it down but this is really a guess out of nothing.

Comment: The`S1.time`  in the WHERE clause makes the left join behave like a plain join.

Comment: Note;I did some formatting to avoid the need for horizontal scrolling.

Comment: You could also show us the existing indexes. Find them with ```\d abc``` and ```\d xyz```

Comment: @wildplasser In which query are you talking about it 1st one or the second one

Comment: @Islingre there are no indexes on xyz table,but are there on abc table

Comment: It might be useful to know on which columns these indexes are.. pls post the relevant part of the output of the ```\d```.

Comment: Show the ```EXPLAIN``` for your first query and perhaps an ```EXPLAIN ANALYZE``` for the second. No "analyze" for the first since you say it takes "forever". If it is just 10 minutes, put analyze here as well

Comment: @Divya Both!  (also: the naming/numbering of S1 and S2 is contra-intuitive, to say the least)